# Types of Questions

Tags: questions, rhetorical-devices

Are questions such as "Will they like me?" and "Will I fit in?" said in a diary, for example, with an emotional tone, rhetorical questions? If not, what type are they?

Comment: I would not class them as obviously rhetorical. Rhetorical questions look for a reaaction rather than an answer because they have an implied answer: "Do you want more freedom or do you want to spend your lives as slaves!" (The implied answers are "Yes" and "No" respectively.)  "Will they like me?" and "Will I fit in?" do not have an implied answer.

Comment: They're introspective questions, but that's not a fixed phrase.

Comment: It's determined by context.

Comment: @Greybeard That's exactly what I was thinking. Thanks. I presume you don't know of any other specific name to class those exact types of questions in?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks, I think that'll work great in my writing.

Comment: @Charlie No. I can't. In the context you give, they are questions the writer asked of themselves and showing a lack of confidence.